# how to authorize callkit in xcode8 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, xcode8-beta6, callkit

How to authorize callkit, CXProvider.authorizationStatus is not avilable in latest version of xcode8 beta.

```
    let cxpor = CXProvider(configuration: conf)
    cxpor?.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not available because authorization is no longer needed to use the API.

Comment: This looks to be right. When I first saw that CallKit required permissions, I was really annoyed. After all, it provides zero access to information on the device, and it seems unlikely that anyone who downloads an app that could benefit from CallKit wouldn't want it to work that way. Glad the permissions requirement was removed.